# How did the Children of the Forest lose control over the White Walkers?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

So, we see in season six, episode five that the [Children of the Forest](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Children_of_the_Forest) create the White Walkers to to protect themselves from the First Men.

Because they made the Walkers to protect them against the First Men, I am assuming they controlled them.

### So how did they lose control over them? Or did they ever have control over them? And why can't they control them now?

Comment: How do you know they controlled the White Walkers in the first place?

Comment: @Gallifreyan, I don't, it is an assumption. Something I was hoping the answer would clear up.

Comment: I'd say that's an invalid assumption. How many stories do we have where the creators can't control the creation?

Comment: @muru, an assumption is an assumption. If you think it is wrong write and answer and I will gladly accept it if it has sources.

Comment: @muru And in how many of those stories were the creations *supposed* to be under control?

Comment: @MishaRosnach most of them, but the Children haven't read them, I guess.

Comment: I'm throwing shade here a little bit, but I don't think the 'ASOIAF' tag is needed here, since we don't know if that's the same origin story which will transpire. Also, as a result of that, we probably won't have an answer to this.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a cannon answer yet. We won't know until either sason 7 or Winds of Winter. Unless GRRM decides to make us wait until book seven comes out to tell us. That's a possibility as well.

Comment: Voting to close this (for now) as part of our [Future works policy](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/5187/21267)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as part of the "future-works" policy.